# Question about Array Indexing in MATLAB Program

Tags: matlab

I try to get the number of groups corresponding to the range from the following code, and define the range variables star_row, end_row, and I have a total of 8950 rows of data.
But I found a bug that the code will error if star_row does not start from 1. I cannot find the issue.

```
plot(time_a(star_row:end_row),acceleration(star_row:end_row,2),'b','LineWidth',1.5);
```

This my code

```
%D1

close all;

acceleration=gpu_load(1:end,:);
N = size(acceleration,1);
star_row = 3762 ;
end_row = N ;

test = acceleration(star_row:end_row,2).^2;
% non_zero number
non_zero = acceleration(acceleration(star_row:end_row,2) ~= 0, 2);
[dec_max, dec_max_idx] = max((acceleration(star_row:end_row,2).^2).^0.5);
[dec_min, dec_min_idx] = min((non_zero.^2).^0.5);
% GPU average
dec_avg = mean(non_zero);
time_a = (acceleration(star_row:end_row,1)-acceleration(1,1))/10^9;
time_satr = 1;
time_end = size(time_a,1);

figure
hold on
plot(time_a(star_row:end_row),acceleration(star_row:end_row,2), 'b','LineWidth',1.5);
plot(time_a(dec_max_idx),acceleration(dec_max_idx,2), '^r','MarkerSize',10);
plot(time_a(dec_min_idx),acceleration(dec_min_idx,2), '^r','MarkerSize',10);

h1 = legend('GPU usage',sprintf('Maximum GPU Usage = %0.3f', dec_max),sprintf('Minimum GPU Usage = %0.3f', dec_min), sprintf('Mean GPU Usage = %0.3f', dec_avg));
set(h1,'FontSize',15);
set(gca,'FontSize',15);

xlabel('Time (Sec)','FontSize',15,'FontWeight','bold');
ylabel('GPU usage','FontSize',15,'FontWeight','bold');

axis([star_row end_row 0 150]);
hold off
grid on
```

Error message：

```
Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must exceed 5189.

Error in draw (line 23)
plot(time_a(star_row:end_row),acceleration(star_row:end_row,2), 'b','LineWidth',1.5);
```

Thanks a lot for any advice

I tried changing the scope to confirm the source of his error

Comment: well, wither `time_a` or `acceleration` are not 8950 as you think they are, but instead 5189. That is the issue.

Comment: It is hard to know what the problem is, because we don’t have a full view of the problem. What is `gpu_load`? You should also remove all the lines of code that don’t contribute to the problem, as described in [mre], so we don’t have to spend so much time reading all your code and figure out what is happening. Make it easy for people to help you!

Comment: to Anthony Chen : Please include in question the size of gpu_load. You mention 8950 rows, how many columns? 3D? Also please detail the range of the values within gpu_load. Is such range for instance [0 255] or else?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the size of array time_a is N-start_row, and you need replace

```
plot(time_a(star_row:end_row),acceleration(star_row:end_row,2), 'b','LineWidth',1.5);
```

to something like that

```
plot(time_a(1:N-start_row),acceleration(star_row:end_row,2), 'b','LineWidth',1.5);
```

because time_a array is smaller then acceleration